# HtmlWebpackPlugin emits no hook

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have a Webpack config where `HtmlWebpackPlugin` loads `pug` files via `@webdiscus/pug-loader` and then it must prettify HTML code with `HtmlPrettifyPlugin` but this is not happening. During the experiments I get that `HtmlWebpackPlugin.beforeEmit` hook does not fire and then that no hook of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` does. Why is that can be?

A part of `webpack.config.babel.js`
(Some variables which not defined here are just parameters of type `string`)

```js
export default {
 //...
 module: {
  rules: [
   //...
   {
    test: /\.html$/i,
    loader: "html-loader",
    options: {
     sources: true,
     esModule: true,
     minimize: false,
    },
   },
   {
    test: /\.pug$/,
    use: [
     {
      loader: "@webdiscus/pug-loader",
      options: {
       compileDebug: true,
       esModule: true,
       basedir: paths.src.base,
       data: {
        isDev: false,
        prefix: config.html.publicPath,
        publicPath: config.html.publicPath,
       },
      },
     },
    ],
   }
  ],
  plugins: [
   //...
   () => glob
    .sync('{src/pages/*.pug,src/pages/**/index.pug}', {cwd})
    .map((file) => {
        const name = file.split('pages')[1];
        const dirName = path.dirname(name).substring(1);
        const dir = dirName ? `${dirName}/` : dirName;

        return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: `${paths.src.pages}${name}`,
            filename: `${dir}${path.basename(name, '.pug')}.html`,
            inject: true,
            minify: false,
        })
    })
  ],
  new HtmlPrettifyPlugin(),
  //...
 }
 //...
}
```

A part of `HtmlPrettifyPlugin` (index.js)

```js
class HtmlPrettifyPlugin {
 //...
 apply(compiler) {
  compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('HtmlPrettifyPlugin', (compilation) => {
   //this function is surely called while `npm run build`
   HtmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation).beforeEmit.tapAsync('HtmlPrettifyPlugin',
    (data, callback) => {
      // this code shows no activirty while `npm run build`
      data.html = beautify(data.html, this.options)
      callback(null, data)
    });
  });
 }
 //...
}
module.exports = HtmlPrettifyPlugin
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a reason of the issue is bad NPM package

Comment: you can try to use the [pug-plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-plugin) instead of HtmlWebpackPlugin, html-loader, @webdiscus/pug-loader. The Pug plugin has the [pretty option](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-plugin#pretty) and contains the same @webdiscus/pug-loader as `PugPlugin.loader`